# Domain Modeling and Mapping with EF CPT5

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to model out a album that has a collection of photos. Each Album will have a collection of Photos and a Photo that is a thumb. This is what I have but EF does not seem to like it. I am using EF CPT5

**The Model**:

```
public class Album : IEntity {
  private DateTime _dateCreated;
  public Album() {
    _dateCreated = SystemTime.Now();
    Photos = new List<Photo>();
  }

  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Location { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateCreated {  get { return _dateCreated; }  set { _dateCreated = value; } }

  public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
  public virtual Photo Thumbnail { get; set; }
  public long ThumbnailId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
 }



public class Photo : IEntity {
  public Photo() {
    _dateCreated = SystemTime.Now();
  }
  private DateTime _dateCreated;
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Caption { get; set; }
  public string FileName { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateCreated<br/>{ get { return _dateCreated; } set { _dateCreated = value; } }
  public long AlbymId { get; set; }
  public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
 }
```

**The Mapping Code:**

```
public class AlbumMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Album> {
  public AlbumMap() {
    HasRequired(x => x.Thumbnail).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.ThumbnailId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        Property(x => x.Location).IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(80);
        Property(x => x.Name).IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(80).IsRequired();
    }
 }

 public class PhotoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Photo> {
  public PhotoMap() {
    HasRequired(p => p.Album).WithMany(a => a.Photos).HasForeignKey(p => p.AlbymId);
    Property(x => x.FileName).IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.Caption).IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(255);
    Property(x => x.DateCreated);
    ToTable("SiteAlbumPhotos");
    }
 }
```

**Context**

```
public class Database : ObjectContext {

        public Database(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection) {
            ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        }

        private IObjectSet<User> _users;
        private IObjectSet<Site> _sites;
        private IObjectSet<SiteDonation> _donations;
        private IObjectSet<SiteAnnouncement> _siteAnnouncements;
        private IObjectSet<SiteData> _siteData;
        private IObjectSet<SiteLink> _siteLinks;
        private IObjectSet<SitePost> _sitePosts;
        private IObjectSet<Theme> _theme;
        private IObjectSet<Album> _siteAlbums;
        private IObjectSet<Photo> _siteAlbumPhotos;
        private IObjectSet<CommunityPost> _communityPosts;
        private IObjectSet<CommunityComment> _communityComments;

        public IObjectSet<User> Users {
            get{ return _users ?? (_users = ObjectSet<User>()); }
        }
        public IObjectSet<Album> SiteAlbums {
            get { return _siteAlbums ?? (_siteAlbums =  ObjectSet<Album>()); }
        }
        public IObjectSet<Photo> SiteAlbumsPhotos {
            get { return _siteAlbumPhotos ?? (_siteAlbumPhotos = ObjectSet<Photo>()); }
        }
        public IObjectSet<Site> Sites {
            get{ return _sites ?? (_sites = ObjectSet<Site>()); }
        }

        public IObjectSet<SiteDonation> SiteDonations {
            get { return _donations ?? (_donations = ObjectSet<SiteDonation>()); }
        }

        public IObjectSet<SiteAnnouncement> SiteAnnouncements {
            get { return _siteAnnouncements ?? (_siteAnnouncements = ObjectSet<SiteAnnouncement>()); }
        }

        public IObjectSet<SiteData> SiteData {
            get { return _siteData ?? (_siteData = ObjectSet<SiteData>()); }
        }

        public IObjectSet<SiteLink> SiteLinks {
            get { return _siteLinks ?? (_siteLinks = ObjectSet<SiteLink>()); }
        }

        public IObjectSet<SitePost> SitePosts {
            get { return _sitePosts ?? (_sitePosts = ObjectSet<SitePost>()); }
        }

        public IObjectSet<Theme> Themes { 
            get { return _theme ?? (_theme = ObjectSet<Theme>()); }
        }
        public IObjectSet<CommunityPost> CommunityPosts {
            get { return _communityPosts ?? (_communityPosts = ObjectSet<CommunityPost>()); }
        }
        public IObjectSet<CommunityComment> CommunityComments {
            get { return _communityComments ?? (_communityComments = ObjectSet<CommunityComment>()); }
        }

        public virtual IObjectSet<T> ObjectSet<T>() where T : class, IEntity {
            return CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }
        public virtual void Commit() {
            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**DatabaseFactory**

```
public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory
    {
        private static readonly ModelBuilder builder = CreateBuilder();
        private readonly DbProviderFactory _providerFactory;
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private Database _database;
        //
        public DatabaseFactory(DbProviderFactory providerFactory, string connectionString)
        {
            Check.Argument.IsNotNull(providerFactory, "providerFactory");
            Check.Argument.IsNotNullOrEmpty(connectionString, "connectionString");
            _providerFactory = providerFactory;
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        //
        public Database Get()
        {
            if(_database == null)
            {
                var connection = _providerFactory.CreateConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                //_database = builder.CreateModel(connection); LEG 1 CPT 3
                //var ctx = dbModel.CreateObjectContext<ObjectContext>(_connectionString); LEG 1 CPT 3
                //var modelBuilder = builder.CreateModel(); LEG 2 CPT 4
                //_database = modelBuilder.CreateObjectContext<Database>(connection); LEG 2 CPT 4
                //_database = modelBuilder.CreateObjectContext<Database>(connection); LEG 2 CPT 4
                var modelBuilder = builder.Build(connection);
                var dbModel = new DbModel(modelBuilder);
                _database = dbModel.CreateObjectContext<Database>(connection);

            }

            return _database;
        }
        //
        protected override void DisposeCore()
        {
            if (_database != null)
            {
                _database.Dispose();
            }
        }
        //
        private static ModelBuilder CreateBuilder()
        {
            //ContextBuilder<Database> contextBuilder = new ContextBuilder<Database>();
            var contextBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
            //IEnumerable<Type> configurationTypes = typeof(DatabaseFactory)
            //    .Assembly
            //    .GetTypes()
            //    .Where(type => type.IsPublic && type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericType && typeof(StructuralTypeConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(type) && (type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null));

            //foreach (StructuralTypeConfiguration configuration in configurationTypes.Select(type => (StructuralTypeConfiguration)Activator.CreateInstance(type)))
            //{
            //    contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(configuration);
            //}
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommunityCommentMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommunityPostMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteAlbumMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteAlbumPhotoMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteAnnouncementMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteDataMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteDonationMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteLinkMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SitePostMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ThemeMap());
            contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
            return contextBuilder;
        }
    }
```

Am I Modeling and Mapping this correctly? I need to be able to create a new Album without specifying a Thumbnail. As of now, it all works till I try to add a Thumbnail, then I get this error:

System.Data.UpdateException: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.DependencyOrderingError(IEnumerable`1 remainder)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at PostHope.Infrastructure.DataAccess.Database.Commit() in Database.cs: line 74
at PostHope.Infrastructure.DataAccess.IntegrationTests.BuildDatabase.Add_test_data_to_database() in BuildDatabase.cs: line 252

**Any help would be great!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tackled this question by EF CTP4 [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355998/domain-modeling-question-using-c-with-entity-framework-ctp-4/4359593#4359593). Now here is the update for EF CTP5 which has been [*released*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-released.aspx) earlier today.

```
public class Photo 
{
    public long PhotoId { get; set; }        
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Caption { get; set; }        
    [MaxLength(255)][Required]
    public string FileName { get; set; }        
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public long AlbumId { get; set; }        
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}

[Table("SiteAlbumPhotos")]
public class Album 
{
    public long AlbumId { get; set; }        
    [MaxLength(80)][Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string Location { get; set; }        
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }                
    public long ThumbnailId { get; set; }                
    public virtual Photo Thumbnail { get; set; }                
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}  

public class PhotoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Photo> {
    public PhotoMap() {            
        HasRequired(p => p.Album).WithMany(a => a.Photos)
                                 .HasForeignKey(p => p.AlbumId);
    }
}

public class AlbumMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Album> {
    public AlbumMap() {
        HasRequired(a => a.Thumbnail).WithMany()
                                     .HasForeignKey(a => a.ThumbnailId)
                                     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add<Photo>(new PhotoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add<Album>(new AlbumMap());
    }
}
```

Which results to this DB schema:
[image]

Comment: Thanks again! I am getting this error when I try to create the database : System.Data.UpdateException: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values. Any ideas??

Comment: Have you exactly copied and pasted my model, or changed yours based on my post? The DB Schema that you see in my answer is captured as the result of running this model against CTP5 so it's 100% tested and working. If you use any custom code, please post it so that I can see what's going on there. Thanks.

Comment: I am using IObjectSet and ObjectContext in my context. I have not rebuild my contex and my Repository yet to use DbContext and DbSet because I will have to re-write a bunch of tests and and to use Compiled Queries is different. I am also using the fluent API not data annotations. There is to much code to post I think, if you like I can give you access to the SVN repo. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I added my contex and DatabaseFactory. Let me know what I need to change or if I am better of just rebuilding my contex with DbContex and DbSet.

Comment: Using Fluent API is fine, I intentionally turn some of your Fluent API mappings to data annotation to show you some new CTP5 features and how you don't need to resort to Fluent API anymore.

Comment: Using ObjectContext with code first could be the cause of the issue and I think you should *definitely* consider to use DbContext. You have to do it anyways, the sooner the better, specially that in CTP5 the underlying ObjectContext is now available via an explicitly implemented interface which allows external components to make use of it like `((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext` rather than being a protected member as it was in CTP4, so hopefully you wouldn't have to change so much code to migrate to DBContext.

Comment: Will update the app this weekend. Will also have to look into compiled queries since CompiledQuery.Compile(expression) complained when I changed to DbSet as a test. Thanks for taking the time to check this our for me. FYI, I am now following your blog. Looking forward to some good posts!

Comment: You're very welcome and yea, I think that's the best. If you run into any problems, just post a question and we'll take care of it :) Also, thanks for checking my blog! I've started writing about CTP5 and will post it soon. If you are in Twitter, please follow me in there (@mmanavi) so that you'll be notified once I publish it :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I've been banging my head against a wall with this exact issue and your sample solved it.